# wpf commands and CustomControl

Tags: wpf, command, custom-controls

`MyCustomControl` provides a zoom `RoutedCommand`.
This `ZoomCommand` is defined as follows:

```
ZoomCommand = new RoutedCommand( "ZoomCommand", typeof( MyCustomControl) );
this.CommandBindings.Add( new CommandBinding( ZoomCommand, zoomCommandHandler,
    ( s, e ) => e.CanExecute = this.IsZoomEnabled ) );
```

I bind to this command in my app with a `KeyBinding` like this:

```
<KeyBinding Key="Add" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=myCustomControl}"
            Command="{Binding ElementName=myCustomControl, Path=ZoomCommand}" />
```

Question:
Now I need to add more logic to enable/disable the execution of the command; one more `CanExecute`.
This logic is unknown to `myCustomControl` and need to be added somewhere else at application level.

I though KeyBinding provided a `CanExecute` itself but it does not.

How do you handle the execution of the command in this case?

Comment: Do you want to handle `CanExecute` method of ZoomCommand from another class, not from `MyCustomControl`?